# Change color smoothly from left to right on hover

Tags: css, animation, transition

This is my simple code :

```
li::after {
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
  border-right: 1px white;
  content: '';
}


li:hover:after {
   position: relative;
   transition: 3s ease;
   height: 2px;
   display: block;
   background: rgb(34, 130, 193);
   border-right: 1px white;
   content: '';
}
```

Now my goal is to make the line change color smoothly from LEFT to RIGHT. But the way I wrote it it just changes color smoothly. I want to give it a direction is there any easy way to do it ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am searching for a behaviour like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/14/). Just to give you an impression how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

Is linear-gradient(color1, color2) what you are looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: I think no. See the link in the EDIT.

Comment: It seem not possible atm to do a transition over a gradient. You can achieve it by transitioning opacity of a helper element though. I updated your fiddle as an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/0ou3o9rn/23/